# How to prove: $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{|f''(x)|}{f(x)}dx>4,$ using elementary math tools.

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, integral-inequality

Let $f\in C^2 [0,1]$ and $f(0)=0=f(1)$ and for all $x\in (0,1)$ we have $f(x)>0$. Prove that

> $$ \int_0^1 \dfrac{|f''(x)|}{f(x)}dx>4.$$

I want to prove this problem with elementary math tools. It is given to the first year university students as a calculus exercise. It is noticed that:

Hint: Use average value theorem in suitable intervals.

Comment: it is not duplicate. I want an elementary proof of the problem not advanced one.

Comment: The proof given in that linked question seems elementary to me (or at least can be turned into something elementary by replacing some vocabulary by the actual definitions). Perhaps you could make precise what you mean by "elementary". If not, then this is a guessing game rather than a mathematics question.

Comment: @MohamadiSudabe: I have added a possibly more elementary answer to the linked question.